# which certificate is used by smartclient application

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have an .net smartclient application OA.Smart.WinUI. I have three .pfx files listed in this project OA.Smart.WinUI_1_TemporaryKey.pfx,OA.Smart.WinUI_2_TemporaryKey.pfx,OA.Smart.WinUI_TemporaryKey.pfx. I want to know which out of these three is being used by this application. I can just find the details by clicking signing tab in properties.

I need this information as i want to change the config file on production server using mageUI.exe. For this i need to sign it again and there is no production certificate. So my understanding is that i need to publish one out of these three files and while signing use the one with which the application has been signed on the development machine.

Please help me out.

Comment: This question should be moved to either Super User or Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MageUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55(VS.80).aspx) and resign both of your manifest files on the production server.  It doesn't matter what they were signed with originally.

I don't know what version of Visual Studio you are using, but in later versions you don't have to sign your manifests at all.  That may be an option as well.

Comment: If you're using SP1, you should be able to go the the "Signing" tab and uncheck "Sign the ClickOnce manifests".